# Flutter Firebase Authentication getIdToken not valid

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, google-signin

I was trying to get id token from google sign in (Firebase Auth)
i already put my sha1 and sha256 into the firebase console, therefore i'm able to sign in and get the id token.

here's my code
`FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
User user;

```
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();

if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final UserCredential userCredential =
      await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

  user = userCredential.user;
}

String token_id = await user.getIdToken(true);

return token_id;`
```

but the id token is **invalid** when i check it at https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=

please help!